# Snowflake date format change

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

Is there an easy way convert a date format from ('2020-11-17') to November 17,2020 in snowflake.

Thanks

Comment: `Nov` is easier than `November` - would that work?

Comment: in my case it should be full month name ( November)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using:

```
TO_CHAR(date, 'MMMM DD yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED THIS PROBLEM USING BELOW SYNTAX:

```
TO_CHAR(date,'MMMM')||' '||TO_CHAR(date,'DD')||','||TO_CHAR(date,'yyyy')
```

Comment: did you try `TO_CHAR(date, 'MMMM DD yyyy')`??

Comment: @Onyambu . . . You should add that as an answer so it can at least be upvoted.

Comment: @Onyambu, the format i needed was different from your answer.

Comment: @zoom what does this give?